# Android 6.0 Permission Error

Tags: android

I'm getting this error:

```
getDeviceId: Neither user 10111 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
```

I had given it in manifest though. Is there any changes regarding **Android 6.XX Marshmallow** devices? I need to give `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission for getting device's IMEI. Pls. Help.

Comment: Try this it may be help you:-http://stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes permissions have changed on Android M. Permissions are now requested at runtime as opposed to install time previous to Android M.

You can check out the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html)

> This release introduces a new permissions model, where users can now directly manage app permissions at runtime. This model gives users improved visibility and control over permissions, while streamlining the installation and auto-update processes for app developers. Users can grant or revoke permissions individually for installed apps.
>
> On your apps that target Android 6.0 (API level 23) or higher, make sure to check for and request permissions at runtime. To determine if your app has been granted a permission, call the new checkSelfPermission() method. To request a permission, call the new requestPermissions() method. Even if your app is not targeting Android 6.0 (API level 23), you should test your app under the new permissions model.
>
> For details on supporting the new permissions model in your app, see Working with System Permissionss. For tips on how to assess the impact on your app, see Permissions Best Practices.

To check for permissions you have to check like this, taken from [github](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RuntimePermissions)

```
public class MainActivity extends SampleActivityBase
        implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {

    public static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    /**
     * Id to identify a camera permission request.
     */
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0;

    // Whether the Log Fragment is currently shown.
    private boolean mLogShown;

    private View mLayout;

    /**
     * Called when the 'show camera' button is clicked.
     * Callback is defined in resource layout definition.
     */
    public void showCamera(View view) {
        // Check if the Camera permission is already available.
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Camera permission has not been granted.

            requestCameraPermission();

        } else {

            // Camera permissions is already available, show the camera preview.
            showCameraPreview();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Requests the Camera permission.
     * If the permission has been denied previously, a SnackBar will prompt the user to grant the
     * permission, otherwise it is requested directly.
     */
    private void requestCameraPermission() {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
            // Provide an additional rationale to the user if the permission was not granted
            // and the user would benefit from additional context for the use of the permission.
            // For example if the user has previously denied the permission.
            Snackbar.make(mLayout, R.string.permission_camera_rationale,
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                    .setAction(R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                                    REQUEST_CAMERA);
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
        } else {

            // Camera permission has not been granted yet. Request it directly.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    REQUEST_CAMERA);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display the {@link CameraPreviewFragment} in the content area if the required Camera
     * permission has been granted.
     */
    private void showCameraPreview() {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.sample_content_fragment, CameraPreviewFragment.newInstance())
                .addToBackStack("contacts")
                .commit();
    }

    /**
     * Callback received when a permissions request has been completed.
     */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
            @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {

            // Received permission result for camera permission.est.");
            // Check if the only required permission has been granted
            if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Camera permission has been granted, preview can be displayed
                Snackbar.make(mLayout, R.string.permision_available_camera,
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Snackbar.make(mLayout, R.string.permissions_not_granted,
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mLayout = findViewById(R.id.sample_main_layout);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            RuntimePermissionsFragment fragment = new RuntimePermissionsFragment();
            transaction.replace(R.id.sample_content_fragment, fragment);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer is perfect. I also wish to add a link to blog, where it is explained "http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en"

Comment: @SHS
edit your blog url and remove last " character.
thanks

Comment: Thankx @SayedAbolfazlFatemi for pointing the error. The corrected blog link is  -    http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en

Comment: "Manifest.permission.CAMERA" did not work with me because it was importing from com.myapp.mypackage.manifest so i had to specify  "android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA".Hope it helps some one.

Answer (score 11):

I modified @Modge's code,
in my case I needed to ask for IMEI permission and the best way to go is during runtime so i did this:

```
   /**
 * A loading screen after AppIntroActivity.
 */
public class LoadingActivity extends BaseActivity {
private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE = 0;
private TextView loading_tv2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading);

    //trigger 'loadIMEI'
    loadIMEI();
    /** Fading Transition Effect */
    overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
}

/**
 * Called when the 'loadIMEI' function is triggered.
 */
public void loadIMEI() {
    // Check if the READ_PHONE_STATE permission is already available.
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // READ_PHONE_STATE permission has not been granted.
        requestReadPhoneStatePermission();
    } else {
        // READ_PHONE_STATE permission is already been granted.
        doPermissionGrantedStuffs();
    }
}



/**
 * Requests the READ_PHONE_STATE permission.
 * If the permission has been denied previously, a dialog will prompt the user to grant the
 * permission, otherwise it is requested directly.
 */
private void requestReadPhoneStatePermission() {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)) {
        // Provide an additional rationale to the user if the permission was not granted
        // and the user would benefit from additional context for the use of the permission.
        // For example if the user has previously denied the permission.
        new AlertDialog.Builder(LoadingActivity.this)
                .setTitle("Permission Request")
                .setMessage(getString(R.string.permission_read_phone_state_rationale))
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //re-request
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LoadingActivity.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
                    }
                })
                .setIcon(R.drawable.onlinlinew_warning_sign)
                .show();
    } else {
        // READ_PHONE_STATE permission has not been granted yet. Request it directly.
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
    }
}

/**
 * Callback received when a permissions request has been completed.
 */
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE) {
        // Received permission result for READ_PHONE_STATE permission.est.");
        // Check if the only required permission has been granted
        if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // READ_PHONE_STATE permission has been granted, proceed with displaying IMEI Number
            //alertAlert(getString(R.string.permision_available_read_phone_state));
            doPermissionGrantedStuffs();
        } else {
            alertAlert(getString(R.string.permissions_not_granted_read_phone_state));
          }
    }
}

private void alertAlert(String msg) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(LoadingActivity.this)
            .setTitle("Permission Request")
            .setMessage(msg)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // do somthing here
                }
            })
            .setIcon(R.drawable.onlinlinew_warning_sign)
            .show();
}


public void doPermissionGrantedStuffs() {
    //Have an  object of TelephonyManager
    TelephonyManager tm =(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    //Get IMEI Number of Phone  //////////////// for this example i only need the IMEI
    String IMEINumber=tm.getDeviceId();

    /************************************************
     * **********************************************
     * This is just an icing on the cake
     * the following are other children of TELEPHONY_SERVICE
     *
     //Get Subscriber ID
     String subscriberID=tm.getDeviceId();

     //Get SIM Serial Number
     String SIMSerialNumber=tm.getSimSerialNumber();

     //Get Network Country ISO Code
     String networkCountryISO=tm.getNetworkCountryIso();

     //Get SIM Country ISO Code
     String SIMCountryISO=tm.getSimCountryIso();

     //Get the device software version
     String softwareVersion=tm.getDeviceSoftwareVersion()

     //Get the Voice mail number
     String voiceMailNumber=tm.getVoiceMailNumber();


     //Get the Phone Type CDMA/GSM/NONE
     int phoneType=tm.getPhoneType();

     switch (phoneType)
     {
     case (TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA):
     // your code
     break;
     case (TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM)
     // your code
     break;
     case (TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE):
     // your code
     break;
     }

     //Find whether the Phone is in Roaming, returns true if in roaming
     boolean isRoaming=tm.isNetworkRoaming();
     if(isRoaming)
     phoneDetails+="\nIs In Roaming : "+"YES";
     else
     phoneDetails+="\nIs In Roaming : "+"NO";


     //Get the SIM state
     int SIMState=tm.getSimState();
     switch(SIMState)
     {
     case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT :
     // your code
     break;
     case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_NETWORK_LOCKED :
     // your code
     break;
     case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PIN_REQUIRED :
     // your code
     break;
     case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PUK_REQUIRED :
     // your code
     break;
     case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY :
     // your code
     break;
     case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN :
     // your code
     break;

     }
     */
    // Now read the desired content to a textview.
    loading_tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loading_tv2);
    loading_tv2.setText(IMEINumber);
}
}
```

Hope this helps you or someone.

Answer (score 6):

I did something like this :

```
    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
        } else {
            setDeviceImei();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                           int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            setDeviceImei();
        }
    }

    private void setDeviceImei() {
        mTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
//Code
.........
..............

  }
```

How i will get List of Permission that i need to set at runtime..?

Comment: I'm Getting Error : NoSuchMethodError : on checkSelfPermission, i can handle it by checking the build version but i't won;t be a generalised solution, is it really necessary to do that as if on production it would be a band aid solution for marshmellow.

Answer (score 0):

We can find all dangerous permissions from  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html

Yet I think it is a bit annoying to check and request dangerous permissions at runtime.So I just make do with TARGET_SDK_VERSION = 22, a lazy guy (╰_╯)

Answer (score 0):

in error code place hit the alt+Enter and auto added annotations. that will fix your problem.