# Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException:android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am trying support my app android M?I have some permission need to ask explicitly at run time.I am was able access other permissions at run time but  "**android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE**" causing SecurityException.

**Here is my manifest file:**

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<!-- Map related permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!--  -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

Comment: Please post your gradle code

Comment: https://developer.android.com/intl/in/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: @Amy I am using eclipse..I dont see any gradle.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya, I have gone though that post,I have create sample app to test it works well,I could able read "READ_PHONE_STATE"..only in my old app if try to achieve same thing I am getting exception..

Answer (score 1):

In your app's build.gradle

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="14"
android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
```

change to

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="14"
android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

And remove these line from manifest.xml.
Then it will work in android M also.

Refer this

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "your.package.name"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        // other lines defaultConfig
    }
 // other lines in android
}
```

Comment: ,Thanks, Ya I know It will work in target = 22, But I need target version to be 23.

Comment: Yes your right..But I want to achieve the same in target 23...Its not possible in 23?

Comment: this is possible with 23 too. But u need to check permission on each event which required permission. if permission is not granted u need to ask user to give permission.. please refer this http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: @AnkitKumar will this work even if we are not setting maxsdkversion in manifest file? and only minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion ? Have you tested?

Comment: @Stallion : Yeah, it will definitely work. I have implemented it in one of my apps..

Answer (score 1):

For Android 23 or higher, you need to ask explicitly to your users if they want to give you a permission. Two ways to handle this: Set your Max SDK version to be 22 (or lower), or ask the user in the run time in addition to specifying in the manifest file.

More detailed information on how to ask permissions at run time can be found at [Working with System Permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html). "[Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)" session from the first the link explains how to do this in your codes in great details.

That being said, try to do some searches before you post a question. Duplicate questions are not encouraged.

Other links that may help you: [similar question on StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33078003/android-6-0-permission-error)

Answer (score 0):

You need to request for the `permission` when needed, on M devices and handle if the `permission` is not granted.You can refer to android documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need `requestPermissions`, here's some example

```
private final static int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 1002;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        int res = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
        if (res != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                    REQUEST_CODE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION);
        }

    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS:
            if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "READ_PHONE_STATE Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

For more details, please see my code on [GitHub](https://github.com/xdtianyu/CallerInfo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/xdty/callerinfo/activity/MainActivity.java#L214)