# How to get device's IMEI/ESN number with code programming But in android > 6

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions, imei

> My Android version is **Marshmallow 6.0**

How to Find / Get imei number in android > 6 programmatically.

Note : I added READ_PHONE_STATE permission inside AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

And inside MainActivity

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String deviceid = manager.getDeviceId();

//Device Id is IMEI number

Log.d("msg", "Device id " + deviceid);
```

Comment: Check this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33078003/android-6-0-permission-error

Comment: what error you are getting?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> My Android version is **Marshmallow 6.0**

Note : You need Runtime Permissions

I added READ_PHONE_STATE permission inside AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

in MainActivity:

```
private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE = 999;

private TelephonyManager mTelephonyManager;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
    } else {
        getDeviceImei();
    }
....

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                       int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE
            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        getDeviceImei();
    }
}

private void getDeviceImei() {

    mTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String deviceid = mTelephonyManager.getDeviceId();
    Log.d("msg", "DeviceImei " + deviceid);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Also getDeviceId() method was deprecated in API level 26.
So further you need to use getImei() or getAllCellInfo() for fetching imei details.

Answer (score -2):

**Requires Permission: READ_PHONE_STATE**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

/**
 * Gets the device unique id called IMEI. Sometimes, this returns 00000000000000000 for the
 * rooted devices.
 **/
public static String getDeviceImei(Context ctx) {
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    Log.i(Tag, "Return Sim count in device : "+manager.getPhoneCount());
    Log.i(Tag, "Defualt device ID: "+manager.getDeviceId());
    Log.i(Tag, "First Sim IMEI:  "+manager.getDeviceId(0));
    Log.i(Tag, "Secand Sim IMEI "+manager.getDeviceId(1));
    return telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
}
```

*Return null if device ID is not available.*

Comment: Read the question carefully before you copy paste your answer