# Request access for location permission in widget

Tags: android, kotlin, geolocation

I have both `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` in my manifest but assume I need to get the permission granted in realtime. On https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions there is a sample

```
val locationPermissionRequest = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()
    ) { permissions ->
        when {
            permissions.getOrDefault(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, false) -> {
                // Precise location access granted.
            }
            permissions.getOrDefault(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, false) -> {
                // Only approximate location access granted.
            } else -> {
                // No location access granted.
            }
        }
    }
```

but it has compilation "Unresolved reference: registerForActivityResult"

So I thought I could use `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()` as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/40955157/131391 but the first parameter for this method is an `Activity`, while I have only a widget and no activity.

I'm not sure what to try next, to get location permission for my widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [configuration activity](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/appwidgets/configuration), or some other activity in your app's UI, will need to request the permissions.