# How to display image with intent.ACTION_VIEW

Tags: android, android-intent, android-5.1.1-lollipop, android-7.1-nougat

My grammar can run at android 5.1 but is not working at android 7.1....

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Pictures/1481853170451.jpg");
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, file.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);

if (file.exists()) {
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  intent.setDataAndType(path, "image/*");
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
try {                       
  this.startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
}
```

Can any one tell me possible answer. Thank you in advance....

Comment: Android permission issue , Check runtime permission for External Storage read

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android 6.0 Permission Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33078003/android-6-0-permission-error)

Comment: has the same probblem

Answer (score 5):

Here are the steps

1) In AndroidManifest.xml add the following provider inside application tag

```
 <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
```

2) Create provider_paths.xml in res/xml folder with the following sample content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="internal_files" path="DATA/TITLE/"/>
</paths>
```

3) Create the image file in Activity with path as shown below

```
  context.getFilesDir() + File.separator + "DATA" + File.separator + "TITLE"+ File.separator + "sample_image_file"
```

4) open the image file using the following code

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                    new File(context.getFilesDir() + File.separator + "DATA" + File.separator + "TITLE"+ File.separator + "sample_image_file"));
            intent.setDataAndType(photoURI,"image/*");
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "View using"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Camera permission

```
    private static final int REQUEST_STORAGE = 112;


    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                        String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                        if (!hasPermissions(mContext, PERMISSIONS)) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_STORAGE );
                        } else {
                            getImage();
                        }
                    } else {
                        getImage();
                    }

                }
            });
        }
```

get Permissions Result

```
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_STORAGE: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    getImage();
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```

check permissions  for marshmallow

```
    private static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Take image from external storage

```
    public void getImage()
    {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Pictures/1481853170451.jpg");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, file.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);

        if (file.exists()) {
          Intent intent = new Intent();
          intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
          intent.setDataAndType(path, "image/*");
          intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        try {                       
          this.startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        }
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```